# Steam doesn't start Wayland / AMDGPU / 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, steam, amdgpu

I can't get steam to run on my ThinkPad E580 with Ubuntu 18.04 and AMDGPU 18.20 on wayland.

```
/home/robau/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/robau/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: pci id for fd 7: 8086:5917, driver i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/robau/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/robau/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Using DRI3 for screen 0
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/robau/.drirc: No such file or directory.
/home/robau/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/robau/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
```

I tried:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1  SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland steam
```

That got me:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/home/robau/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by /opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-6.0.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

So something about GCC. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the bundled gcc libraries (and some others) seemed to work:

```
find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete
```

See here:
    https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/366298942096376703/